# Does intra-Schengen removal count as deportation or removal from any country?

Tags: schengen, sweden, denmark, removal, deportation

I took the Helsingør to Helsingborg ferry from the Danish side. I was not warned that there would be passport control on the Swedish side before boarding the ferry and, as such, I did not I know I needed to possess my passport that I had left at the hotel.

Sweden denied me entry and sent me back to Denmark after being requested by the Swedish police to sign some paperwork, presented in Swedish only. There was no passport control on the Danish side, and I was able to return to Denmark.

Later, I took the train from Copenhagen to Malmö, where there were passport checks conducted at the border and I was allowed through to Sweden upon presenting my passport.

I am a citizen of a visa-exempt country, and did not require a visa to enter the Schengen area. As this was intra-Schengen border control, will I be required to declare this on any future immigration form for any jurisdiction as a deportation or removal?

Comment: And you signed it?

Comment: Yes, they required me to sign it to take the ferry back to Denmark.

Comment: If unsure, you can always check "Yes, I have been deported" and declare "Sent back at the intra-Schengen border because I had forgotten my passport. Entry permitted N days later." I doubt any Immigration Officer anywhere in the world will hold this against you, since Sweden let you in afterwards...

Comment: I’m unsure about the exact legislation hence this is only a comment but IIRC the legality of the Danish–Swedish border control is highly questionable since it specifically violates Schengen regulations. As a consequence, you were probably *not* legally refused entry, and you should *not* declare this on future applications. However, before doing so *you must talk to an immigration lawyer* to ensure that you will not commit perjury.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For the purposes of Swedish law you were 'avvisad', which is translated as 'refused entry' in the official English edition of the Aliens Act. This term covers all kind of rejections at the border. Someone who is already present in Sweden and for some reason found unworthy to stay, will be 'expelled'. Swedish law uses the term 'expulsion' for any act of 'throwing someone out', be it by leaving voluntarily or escorted with force. The terms 'removal' and 'deporation' are not used at all in Swedish alien law.

Answering you question will however depend on the definition of the terms 'removal' and 'deportation' in the jurisdiction you are involved with in the future.

Gayot Fow used to claim that being refused entry to the UK is considered a 'removal'. I am not familiar with UK immigration law, but if that is true, the action taken against you seem at least to fall within the definition of 'removal' as used in UK law.

Comment: Gayout advocated the principle of it being better to err on the side of declaring and explaining than to get caught in what immigration consider to be a lie.

Comment: @PeterGreen But that’s a false dilemma, and given that such declarations can seriously hurt your chances this sounds like pretty bad advice.

Answer (score 10):

On the other side of the pond, on the US/Canada border, it is routine for a traveler to be told (over something non-scary like "forgot ID"), in as many words, that "this is a really good time for you to withdraw your application to enter our country".

(Because if you pressed onward with your application, you **would** be refused, and that would have immigration consequences for you later.)

What follows is an explanation that

> since you withdrew your application, it means you did not even attempt to enter our country (merely visiting the Immigration office to discuss entering the country does not count as "entering the country").  If you are asked in the future "were you ever refused entry in the past", the correct answer is "no, you were not refused entry".  To be clear, this is not you being refused entry, this is you "willingly deciding not to enter".

For a simple reason such as "forgot passport", and given the ease with which they allowed you to re-enter, you might ask someone to translate that Swedish (post it here?) and see if the above is exactly what the Swedish authorities did with you.  If so, congratulations. You did not enter Sweden.

Comment: There is no concept of withdrawing an application to enter in Swedish immigration law.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Not in American law either, it's more of a nudge and a wink, a clever immigration officer trick to spare harm and reduce system load.  That's a good point, they did make him sign something.

Comment: At least in Canada, the withdrawal of an entry application is a formal process anchored in law. It is not merely a wink from the immigration officer, but includes some paperwork and is kept on file. I am not sure about US law.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the form anymore. I don't recall too much about it, apart from them stating "you need this as your ticket to take the ferry back" and being escorted by a police officer back onto the ferry.

Comment: Oh, that's probably what it was then. Downvoter, I don't like factually wrong answers either, if you can show my answer is wrong, I'll delete it and to heck with the rep :)

Comment: @Harper Are you sure that "withdrew application" has no status in US law? Question 7 in the eligibility section of ESTA applications is, "Have you ever been denied a U.S. visa you applied for with your current or previous passport, or have you ever been refused admission to the United States _or withdrawn your application for admission_ at a U.S. port of entry?" (my emphasis).

Comment: In any case, the question is about Sweden and Schengen. So how is the USA relevant?

Comment: I’m unable to downvote (not enough points) but this answer is wrong since the political situation is *completely different* from that of the intra-Schengen border between Denmark and Sweden. It should really be deleted, since it’s dangerously misleading.

Comment: @KonradRudolph my offer stands. Can you elaborate or provide support?

Comment: @Harper I’m sorry what exactly in my comment needs to be elaborated and supported? Do you doubt that the border between Denmark and Sweden is an intra-Schengen border or that the border between US and Canada is outside of Schengen, or do you not believe that Schengen rules fundamentally change what a border is? Assuming you know what [Schengen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area) refers to, none of these make sense.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'm saying those facts are inadequate to support your claim that this answer is wrong or misleading.  I was clear in my offer that support is needed.  I'm not going to remove a correct and high voted answer on your grumpy naysaying word alone. Of course they're different countries.  Of course Schengen.  But all borders have similar problems, i.e. Having to turn away people for trivial reasons that shouldn't prejudice their future entry.  Similar problems lead to similar solutions.  You have to prove that wrong and "they're different countries!" doesn't begin to cut it.

Comment: @Harper tl;dr: border controls within the Schengen area are not immigration controls, they follow entirely different rules than borders between countries that are specifically governed by the Schengen treaty. “All borders have similar problems” is a flat out wrong claim, and this is *specifically* addressed by the Schengen treaty (in particular, the border controls in question are illegal under the Schengen treaty; there was a temporary exemption but that is no longer in effect).

Answer (score 7):

I tried finding out anything on the local government websites but even in Swedish it is hard to find them using any specific words. These border controls are designed to make immigrants apply for asylum on the spot or return to the country they come from. Sweden as a country is not interested in making this have a lasting effect on your future travels, but cultural and political wishes are not always aligned with the bureaucracy so I would not trust this as an answer.

Your best bet may be to call the Swedish Police on their non-emergency number with your question: `+46 77 114 14 00`

Ask if the event is registered with your name anywhere. Also ask if they have a record of the document you signed, and if they can send you a copy.